# Pascal's Triangle with a Twist

Tags: scheme

Say we want to generate Pascal's Triangle within Scheme, but with a twist. For the function (pascal left right depth), where left is the number on the left side of the triangle and right is the number on the right. For example a call of (pascal 1 1 5) would return

```
      1
     1 1
    1 2 1
   1 3 3 1
  1 4 6 4 1
 1 5 10 10 5 1
```

and a call to (pascal 1 2 5) would return

```
      1
     1 2
    1 3 2
   1 4 5 2
  1 5 9 7 2
 1 6 14 16 9 2
```

How would you print the triangle out so that it is spaced like the examples?

My code so far is as follows but all this does is return which number should be at which location within the standard triangle.

```
(define (pascal x y)
    (cond ((or (<= x 0) (<= y 0) (< x y)) 0)
        ((or (= 1 y) (= x y)) 1)
        (else (+ (pascal (- x 1) y) (pascal (- x 1) (- y 1))))))
```

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far, indicating the specific parts in the code that you're having trouble with

Comment: @ÓscarLópez How would you print a variable number of spaces. Such as say I wanted to print 8 spaces followed by a one. (println (* " " 8) 1) doesn't work for printing it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a decreasing number of spaces to the start of each line. Determine the number from the length of the last line and the length of the current line to be printed.

Comment: How would you print a variable number of spaces. Such as say I wanted to print 8 spaces followed by a one. (println (* " " 8) 1) doesn't work for printing it.

Comment: @user3277752 Use `(make-string 8 " ")` rather than `(* " " 8)` which doesn't work.